# Binary operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type (Int, Int, Int, Int) -> Int

Tags: swift, int, binary-operators

```
var a11: Int = 0
var a12: Int = 0
var a21: Int = 0
var a22: Int = 0

var valueDeterminant = a11 * a12 * a21 + a22

func calculateDeterminant(a11: Int, a12: Int, a21: Int, a22: Int) -> Int {
    return valueDeterminant
}


if calculateDeterminant == 0 {
    print("The trasformation is irreversable, due to the fact that the determinant is \(calculateDeterminant)")
 } else if calculateDeterminant == 1 {
    print("The determinant is\(calculateDeterminant) \nThe trasformation is reverable, and it keeps the area")
 } else {
    print("The determinant is \(calculateDeterminant) \nThe transformation is reversable")
}
```

The error says that the binary operator == cannot be used to types of (Int, Int, Int, Int). Why? And how can I solve this?
Also, if i change the return value to Bool, it comes up another error, saying that I can't put Int values that returns Bool value.

Comment: You're comparing different things, an array to a single value, why do you think that would work

Comment: `calculateDeterminant` is a function – you cannot compare that with `0`. What you probably meant to do was *call* the function, with the appropriate `a11`, `a12`, etc. values (and then change the implementation so it actually uses the arguments instead of `valueDeterminant`).

Comment: or make valueDeterminant  a computed property `var valueDeterminant: Int { return a11 * a12 * a21 + a22 }` and just call `if valueDeterminant == 0 {`

Comment: You also have a few other syntactic things wrong with the code provided. (1) You cannot declare *valueDeterminant* the way you have - this isn't "top down" programming. (2) When you call calculateDeterminant, you need to pass in 4 *named* parameters - a11, a12, a21, a22. Right now, these errors will cause your code to not even build!

Comment: What's wrong with the declaration of `valueDeterminant` @dfd?

Comment: It should look like this `if calculateDeterminant(a11: 1, a12: 2, a21: 3, a22: 4) == 0 {...`  It won't work anyway because you don't do anything with these values inside of your function.

Comment: @hamish - I qualified my comment by stating *the code provided*. Depending on how you paste it into things, it may not compile. I suspect this is stripped code - possibly to the point of not being indicative of the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first class values. You were comparing the function `calculateDeterminant` with a `Int`. Not supported. Call the function, then compare the integer values.

```
var a11: Int = 0
var a12: Int = 0
var a21: Int = 0
var a22: Int = 0

var valueDeterminant = a11 * a12 * a21 + a22

func calculateDeterminant() -> Int {
  return a11 * a12 * a21 * a22
}


if calculateDeterminant() == 0 {
  print("The trasformation is irreversable, due to the fact that the determinant is \(calculateDeterminant())")
} else if calculateDeterminant() == 1 {
  print("The determinant is\(calculateDeterminant()) \nThe trasformation is reverable, and it keeps the area")
} else {
  print("The determinant is \(calculateDeterminant()) \nThe transformation is reversable")
}
```

Or define it like this...

```
func calculateDeterminant(a11: Int, a12: Int, a21: Int, a22: Int) -> Int {
    return a11 * a12 * a21 * a22
}
```

... and call it like this.

```
if (calculateDeterminant(a11: a11, a12: a12, a21: a21, a22: a22) == 0 {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, now the playground doesn't display any error, but when I call the function, any value I assign to the arguments, the result is 0. Why?